# Converting all data in the cells of a column to the same type using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

How can I automatically convert this data to column A in a worksheet with a macro. So that when I paste `(CTRL + V)` into the cells of column A, this data is automatically converted?

For example:

```
F8 300m
N5/6/7 140m
650m X5
235m S2
L3 270M
500m FMA
Nest 475m
340m Pr6
720M uT10
etc.
```

Should automatically convert to:

```
F8 300m
N5/6/7 140m
X5 650m
S2 235m
L3 270M
FMA 500m
Nest 475m
Pr6 340m
uT10 720M
etc.
```

That is, it is necessary that `(any number)m` and `(any number)M` be on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula would work without needing VBA as long as there is always a space and as long as the code before or after the (number)m never ends in an m:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="m",A1,MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1)) & " "& LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1))
```

Comment: This formula works great, but the formula needs to be entered in a different column. I need a macro so that the conversion happens in one column.

Comment: Sub mConvertColumnA()

Dim lRow, lCount As Integer

lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For lCount = 1 To lRow
    If Right(Range("A" & lCount).Value, 1) = "m" Then
        Range("A" & lCount).Value = Range("A" & lCount).Value
    Else
        Range("A" & lCount).Value = Mid(Range("A" & lCount).Value, InStr(1, Range("A" & lCount).Value, " ", 0) + 1, Len(Range("A" & lCount).Value) - InStr(1, Range("A" & lCount).Value, " ", 0)) & " " & Left(Range("A" & lCount).Value, InStr(1, Range("A" & lCount).Value, " ", 0) - 1)
    End If
Next

End Sub

Comment: Thanks! But when using this macro, the data must be entered in advance and then run the macro manually. But I need the macro to automatically run on the sheet when data is inserted. How to convert your macro to work automatically on a sheet?

Comment: You can, it's not always a good idea though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change